# Как сделать топ пользователей в telebot?

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

У меня есть данные пользователей в таблице `users` - `id`, `rating`. Вывести топ пользователей смог, но как это оформить, чтобы было по типу `1. id rating\n2. id rating` и так далее..?

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def test(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT id, rating FROM users order by rating desc limit 10')
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    for user in users:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Айди: {user[0]} Рейтинг: {user[1]}')
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def test(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT id, rating FROM users order by rating desc limit 10')
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="'\n".join(f"Айди: {user[0]} Рейтинг: {user[1]}" for user in users))
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```